# How to change path of welcome html file

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

I have created Dynamic web project and it has .html, .css and .js files. I group these file in respective folders like .js file in javascripts folder and .html file in views folder but i don't able to access these file in project. I used eclipse IDE for this. Is there need to configure path for these folder?

Comment: I'm not sure this question has the right tag(s). Is this about configuring the Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Just HTML , CSS & JS . Why do you need Eclipse IDE ? They are **STATIC** !

Comment: What do you mean by: *i don't able to access these*? Do you mean that the files are not loaded? Please share your code, this question is impossible to answer with it. It's probably that you need to update the paths for your files.

Comment: Also add your folder structure...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the JSP file in /index.jsp instead of in /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp. This way the whole servlet is superflous by the way.

WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    `-- web.xml`
-- index.jsp

If you're absolutely positive that you need to invoke a servlet this strange way, then you should map it on an URL pattern of /index.jsp instead of /index. You only need to change it to get the request dispatcher from request instead of from config and get rid of the whole init() method.

Answer (score 0):

These are not Java source files, so it makes no sense to configure them as such. By default in a Dynamic Web Project you only see the `src` folder under *Java Resources*. Other folders will be listed at the bottom of the tree. This is by design.

Or if you meant, that you do not see them when you move into the folder by an external file manager: press <kbd>F5</kbd> on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Its based on from which file you are trying to access those files.

If it is in the same folder where your working project file is, then you can use just the file name. no need of path.

If it is in the another folder which is under the same parent folder of your working project file then you can use location like in the following `/javascript/sample.js`

In your example if you are trying to access your js file from your html file you can use the following location

`../javascript/sample.js`

the prefix`../` will go to the parent folder of the file(Folder upward journey)

Answer (score 0):

```
I got answer to my question...
Now my directory structure is
WebContent
--javascripts
--stylesheets
--viwes
--META-INF
--WEB-INF
Note: view contain html files

To change path of my welcome html file i made bit change in web.xml present in WEB-INFfolder.

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/views/welcome.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```